# OSMNx: How to fetch street network using saved osm xml instead of overpass api call request

Tags: openstreetmap, osmnx

I can fetch OSM street network using

```
G=ox.graph_from_point((lat, lng),custom_filter=road_filter,dist=20,simplify=False,retain_all=True)
```

The process is very slow if i have to make 1000 of such requests.I was hoping if i can load the saved osm file then query locally for the osm road networks.

Answer (score 0):

In **Osmnx**, the only way to create a graph from a local .osm formatted XML file is:

```
graph = osmnx.graph_from_xml(filepath, simplify=False, retain_all=True)
```

There are not filters as other graph_from_*() functions, but once you got the graph you can query the Geodataframes containing nodes and edges that you get with:

```
nodes, edges = osmnx.graph_to_gdfs(graph, nodes=True, edges=True)
```